# PHP cURL/Socket and HTTP authentication

Tags: php, http, sockets, authentication, curl

I have a webpage with a list of HTML links for images in a protected subfolder.
This folder is protected via .htaccess and **HTTP authentication**.

Is there a way to use cURL/Socket, or something like that, to access to the subfolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_USERPWD, '[username]:[password]') 
$data = curl_exec(); 
curl_close($ch); 
?>
```

[Source](http://www.higherpass.com/php/tutorials/Using-Curl-To-Query-Remote-Servers/5/)

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about HTTP Basic authentication, then you can provide the necessary credentials with

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); // enable HTTP Basic auth
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password"); // credentials
```

There are also some other options that may be of interest such as `CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD` (if you are going through a proxy) and `CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH` (if the initial host redirects you to another domain where the actual authentication takes place).